# Is there a way to modify user e-mail routing via the api?

Tags: google-email-settings-api

I would like to be able to modify user-level e-mail routing via an API, but I can't seem to find a library that will permit this.

Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't currently any way to setup user-level routing with the APIs. The closest thing would be to [use the Email Settings API to setup forwarding](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/email-settings/#manage_forwarding_settings). It isn't quite the same since the messages will still enter the user's Gmail account but it might work for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

In case this is the aim of the OP, the admin API has support for [managing routing](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/admin-settings#managing_email_routing_settings)

```xml
<atom:entry xmlns:atom='http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom' xmlns:apps="http://schemas.google.com/apps/2006">
<apps:property name='routeDestination' value='route-smtp.domain.com'/>
<apps:property name='routeRewriteTo' value='true'/>
<apps:property name='routeEnabled' value='true'/>
<apps:property name='bounceNotifications' value='true'/>
<apps:property name='accountHandling' value='can be either allAccounts | provisionedAccounts | unknownAccounts'/>
</atom:entry>
```